# pc with asus p5k se won't power on

Tags: motherboard

I have a pc with a asus p5k se motherboard.

After powering it down I can't power it back up. The onboard led lights up in standby mode but when I toggle the front panel power button nothing happens.

I thought that maybe I had loosed the connectors between the mother board and the two front panel buttons, so after I unplugged and re-plugged everything it still nothing happens.

Any thoughts or suggestions?

Thanks

EDIT:

bonus round:

- any jumper or other motherboard based setting I could use to bypass the front panel switch.

**EDIT 2**

It was the power supply.

Comment: Is the PC new? Does it have a history of any problems?

Comment: no, not new. No other real problems before.

Comment: Was there anything unusual about how or why you powered the system down the last time?

Comment: no. Win7 start menu. nothing strange.